# React: render() compared to ReactDOM.render()

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a really simple app, using webpack.

In my webpack confing the entry is defined as:

```
entry: {
app: './index.js'
```

},

When my index.js code is defined as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './style.css'
import App from './App'
import store from './app/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I get a "Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element" error.

But when i change it to:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM, {render} from 'react-dom'
import './style.css'
import App from './App'
import store from './app/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

render(<Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>, document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')));
```

Everything works fine. What is the difference between the ReactDOM.render and ther other render function? And what is the first one causes error while the second works?

(or maybe its realted to how i access the root element?)

Comment: Looks like your html file doesn't contain an element with id `root` that's why you're seeing that exception. Can you post your html file code here. Otherwise both the render methods work the same way as they are part of `ReactDOM`.